# How to access the auto-generated ID from a Phinx migration insert?

Tags: php, cakephp, phinx

[PHP Phinx](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/phinx/seeding.html) is a Database Seeder / Migration library from CakePHP.

This will create a fake user, but how would I create a row that has a `FOREIGN KEY` (or regular ID reference) to the `id` of that new user, i.e. a sub-user?

```
<?php

use Phinx\Seed\AbstractSeed;

class UserSeeder extends AbstractSeed
{
    public function run()
    {
        $faker = Faker\Factory::create();
        $data = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
            $data[] = [
                'username'      => $faker->userName,
                'password'      => sha1($faker->password),
                'password_salt' => sha1('foo'),
                'email'         => $faker->email,
                'first_name'    => $faker->firstName,
                'last_name'     => $faker->lastName,
                'created'       => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            ];
        }

        $this->insert('users', $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should return the equivalent of `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`:

```
$this->getAdapter()->getConnection()->lastInsertId();
```

Reference: https://github.com/cakephp/phinx/issues/819

Comment: Exactly what what I needed, thanks. I'd be curious how it behaves with multiple `insert`s before a `save`? Also does it have to be called after `save()`?

Comment: That value would be updated with every `INSERT` operation on the database table, so if you do multiple inserts in a single transaction you'd only see the last one. Note that this isn't table specific either, it will return the last ID from any table that had the most recent insert.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Phinx, so not sure if inserts are queued up and executed with `save()` or what.